# Adapting OSX Application's Images for Retina

Tags: xcode, user-interface, graphics, retina-display

We have an application in development that is currently only utilizing standard display resolution. How do we modify the @2x images for Mac Retina displays?

Say I have a button that is 50 x 100 px. Would I just double the dimensions and add a @2x extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Say I have a button that is 50 x 100 px. Would I just double the dimensions and add a @2x extension?

You should at minimum find the original high resolution artwork, then scale that down to the destination size. In some cases, you will also want a slightly different (e.g. more detailed) image for the high res.

Simply upscaling the existing resource is what one should avoid; it would accomplish nothing when finally drawn (apart from larger app and more memory consumption). That is to say, it would not be "Hi-Res", it would just be a larger image that would look the same to the end user -- rescaling is just happening at a different point in time and the results would *both* be pixelated (or equally blurred, depending on how it were rescaled). The only reason I can think of where you would ever do this would be if you lost (or never had a larger) the original HQ artwork, and wanted to use a rescaled image which was rescaled using a high quality rescaler -- in the event you also do no rescaling when drawing these images.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Say our designer made a high resolution button and then scaled it down to 50px x 100px for regular display. What would the pixel size of the retina version be? 100px x 200px right?

Comment: @user1390395 that's correct. specifically, at 72 pixels per inch. from your wording, i was under the impression that you wanted to simply upscale the current assets to hi res sizes. you may also want to read up on the build setting `COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES`. this will 'embed' the two images into one TIFF file.

Comment: is `COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES` more efficient or a smaller footprint than simply having file.png and file@2x.png in my resources? In iOS I usually do the latter.

Comment: @user1390395 That's a good question! I was also curious about side-effects, although I have not measured. I imagine it could go either way (consider also costs of disk caching and NSImage/UIImage caching, I/O, and deserialization of information related to pages which are never read). Personally, I am still using separate resource files in most cases (like you) -- that's mostly because I want a consistent way to load resources regardless of API used. There are also obvious cases for deduplication; but IDK if TIFF exploits that here.

Answer (score 1):

Retina images on OS X behave the same way as they do in iOS. So, yes, redraw (not scale up) your images, and resave them with their @2x extension.